# How to copy files based on last modified date to network drive?

Tags: powershell

Our Git repo blew up and we ended up losing the repo so now all our our users code is only on local workstations. For temporary storage we are going to have all of them put their local repo's on a network share. I am currently trying to write a PowerShell script to allow users to select all their repos with GridView and then copy them to the network share. This will cause a lot of overlap, so I only want files that have the latest modified date (commit) to overwrite when their are duplicate files.

For example,

User 1 has repo\file.txt last modified 8/10 and uploads it to network share.

User 2 also has repo\file.txt last modifed 8/12. when User 2 copies to the share it should overwrite User 1 file because it is the newer file.

I am new to PowerShell so I am not sure which direction to take. 
As of right now I figured out how to copy over all files, but can't figure out the last modified piece. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$destination = '\\remote\IT\server'

$filesToMove = get-childitem -Recurse | Out-GridView -OutputMode Multiple
$filesToMove | % { copy-item $_.FullName $destination -Recurse }
```

Comment: I did not use Github's API yet but did you try to use the WebRequest function from PowerShell already? 
You suggested code successfully selects all the targeted files?

Comment: @Alex_P Well all of our GIT stuff is wiped out, so really this is just a local directory move to a network share with multiple users problem at this point. i.e. the server hosting our git repos died

Comment: @bryane92 Please ensure you save the `.git` directory from all the local working directories - they hold the commit history and you can literally recover what was "blown up" straight out of these

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen oh wow I didnt even think of that! My question would be then if I have every user add their .git directory to the network share what would be the best way to re-add that back on our git server without tons of conflicts. Multiple users might have the same repo on their local machine and different commit levels.

Comment: The best way would be to collect all of them, then figure out (using git log and git branch) which copy is most up to date relative to the master copy on the server that you lost. This is literally the selling point of git - there's not a central source of history, every copy is a replica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your users have permission to write/delete files in the remote destination path, this should do it:

```
$destination = '\\remote\IT\server\folder'

# create the destination folder if it does not already exist
if (!(Test-Path -Path $destination -PathType Container)) {
    Write-Verbose "Creating folder '$destination'"
    New-Item -Path $destination -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
}

Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\test' -File -Recurse |
    Out-GridView -OutputMode Multiple -Title 'Select one or more files to copy' | ForEach-Object {
        # since we're piping the results of the Get-ChildItem into the GridView, 
        # every '$_' is a FileInfo object you can pipe through to the Copy-Item cmdlet.

        $skipFile = $false
        # create the filename for a possible duplicate in the destination
        $dupeFile = Join-Path -Path $destination -ChildPath $_.Name
        if (Test-Path -Path $dupeFile) {
            # if a file already exists AND is newer than the selected file, do not copy
            if ((Get-Item -Path $dupeFile).LastWriteTime -gt $_.LastWriteTime ) {
                Write-Host "Destination file '$dupeFile' is newer. Skipping."
                $skipFile = $true
            }
        }
        if (!$skipFile) {
            $_ | Copy-Item -Destination $destination -Force
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my first post here so please be forgiving. I'm browsing reddit/stackoverflow looking for cases to practice my PowerShell skills. I tried creating a script like you asked for on my local home PC, let me know if that somehow helps you:

```
$selectedFiles = get-childitem -Path "C:\Users\steven\Desktop" -Recurse | Out-GridView -OutputMode Multiple
$destPath = "D:\"
foreach ($selectedFile in $selectedFiles) {
    $destFileCheck = $destPath + $selectedFile
    if (Test-Path -Path $destFileCheck) {
        $destFileCheck = Get-ChildItem -Path $destFileCheck
        if ((Get-Date $selectedFile.LastWriteTime) -gt (Get-Date $destFileCheck.LastWriteTime)) {
            Copy-Item -Path $selectedFile.FullName -Destination $destFileCheck.FullName
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "Source file is older than destination file, skipping copy."
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm...this does look promising, but an issue I am facing (and have been facing) is that anything out after that GridView doesnt seem to be working. I tested by trying to Write-Host directly after and it doesnt write to console yet when I do a Write-Hose as the first line it comes out fine. Any ideas on that behavior?

Comment: Can't really tell what's causing that. After I selected a few files in Grid-View this is my output:

$selectedFiles

Directory: C:\Users\steven\Desktop

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       16.08.2019     16:56         120836 Survival Race.png

Directory: C:\Users\steven\Desktop\BleachBit-Portable

Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
------       20.03.2019     05:18          47848 bleachbit.exe

Comment: I wonder if the network share is messing it up. It seems like no matter what I select powershell just gets stuck and I cant even ctrl + C out of the process

Comment: That would be rather unusual, I've been successfully using network paths in PowerShell, but sadly that's something I can't really tell more about.